# How to call Executor.map in custom dask graph?

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda, distributed, distributed-computing, dask

I've got a computation, consisting of 3 "map" steps, and the last step depends on results of the first two. I am performing this task using `dask.distributed` running on several PCs.

Dependency graph looks like following.

```
map(func1, list1) -> res_list1-\
                                | -> create_list_3(res_list1, res_list2)-> list3 -> map(func3, list3)
map(func2, list2) -> res_list2-/
```

If we imagine that these computations are independent, then it is straightforward to call `map` function 3 times.

```
from distributed import Executor, progress

def process(jobid):
    e = Executor('{address}:{port}'.format(address=config('SERVER_ADDR'),
                                           port=config('SERVER_PORT')))
    futures = []
    futures.append(e.map(func1, list1))
    futures.append(e.map(func2, list2))
    futures.append(e.map(func3, list3))

    return futures

if __name__ == '__main__':
    jobid = 'blah-blah-blah'
    r = process(jobid)
    progress(r)
```

However, `list3` is constructed from results of `func1` and `func2`, and its creation is not easily `map`pable (`list1`, `list2`, `res_list1` and `res_list2` are stored in the Postgresql database and creation of `list3` is a `JOIN` query, taking some time).

I've tried to add call to `submit` to the list of futures, however, that did not work as expected:

```
def process(jobid):
    e = Executor('{address}:{port}'.format(address=config('SERVER_ADDR'),
                                           port=config('SERVER_PORT')))
    futures = []
    futures.append(e.map(func1, list1))
    futures.append(e.map(func2, list2))
    futures.append(e.submit(create_list_3))
    futures.append(e.map(func3, list3))

    return futures
```

In this case one `dask-worker` has received the task to execute `create_list_3`, but others have simultaneously received tasks to call `func3`, that have erred, because `list3` did not exist.

Obvious thing - I'm missing synchronization. Workers must stop and wait till creation of `list3` is finished.

Documentation to `dask` describes custom task graphs, that can provide a synchronization.

However, examples in the documentation do not include `map` functions, only simple calculations, like calls `add` and `inc`.

Is it possible to use `map` and custom dask graph in my case, or should I implement sync with some other means, that are not included in `dask`?

Comment: Have found this link: https://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/task-launch.html Title is promising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to link dependencies between tasks then you should pass the outputs from previous tasks into the inputs of another.

```
futures1 = e.map(func1, list1)
futures2 = e.map(func2, list2)
futures3 = e.map(func3, futures1, futures2)
```

For any invocation of `func3` Dask will handle waiting until the inputs are ready and will send the appropriate results to that function from wherever they get computed.

However it looks like you want to handle data transfer and synchronization through some other custom means.  If this is so then perhaps it would be useful to pass along some token to the call to `func3`.

```
futures1 = e.map(func1, list1)
futures2 = e.map(func2, list2)

def do_nothing(*args):
    return None

token1 = e.submit(do_nothing, futures1)
token2 = e.submit(do_nothing, futures2)

list3 = e.submit(create_list_3)

def func3(arg, tokens=None):
    ...

futures3 = e.map(func3, list3, tokens=[token1, token2])
```

This is a bit of a hack, but would force all `func3` functions to wait until they were able to get the token results from the previous map calls.

However I recommend trying to do something like the first option. This will allow dask to be much smarter about when it runs and can release resources.  Barriers like `token1/2` result in sub-optimal scheduling.

Comment: Yes, I store actual results in a database, and functions return tokens.